# Invention of calculus

Tags: calculus, book-recommendation

When Newton was off from school for about 2 years he invented calculus. But what were the problems that he saw his way through calculus . can you tell me some book which can tell me how he made it!

Comment: Your question is better suited for this webpage: https://hsm.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Sorry I didn't knew that there is some other webpage to refer for this:(

Comment: But please don't close the Q.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out Leibniz's Monadology. Then you'll learn about some metaphysical motivations for calculus. I think that Leibniz and Newton were inspired somewhat by understanding the physical world but Leibniz is without a doubt the superior philosopher and his motivations for exploring the infinitesimal aren't limited to understanding cosmos/physical reality.

Check out the Philosophiæ Naturalis Principia Mathematica if you want to understand more about Newton and physics... Read Leibniz if you want to have some real insight.

Comment: To be fair, the question was about Newton’s motivations and not Leibniz’s. Though, I am interested in checking out the work of Leibniz that you mentioned.

Comment: Top be fair to Mason, he is doing the asker a big favor redirecting him from the mind of an evil genius to the mind of a glorious angelic genius.

Comment: I answer the question: "Check out Principia..." but while I am here: Stop revering physicists! Philosophers and mathematicians do interesting work which are not motivated by the physical world. The Monadology is short: 13? pages and you can find it read online for free. It's a great intro to Leibniz.